# Converting video for Android using Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: video, conversion, android, h.264, adobe-media-encoder

I'm trying to convert some video to H.264 and play it on my Android mobile phone.
I have Adobe Media Encoder and can easily create files that play on my PC but when I copy them to the phone the media player app just complains that it can't play them.

Are there some particular settings I need to use in the encoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you would need to watch the Encoding profile to be one of the mobile device compatible category, but you'd also need a decent player which support the MP4 files and has a good h264 decoder.

Here is a quote from [an article](http://www.digitalwerks.org/2009/02/27/video-on-the-android-g1/) about  the video capabilities of the G1

> It turns out that the G1’s
>   capabilities are pretty similar to
>   later generation iPods, iPhones and
>   Zunes.  H.264 video on the G1 needs to
>   conform to the Baseline Profile and
>   the 3.0 Level, which govern some of
>   the impermissible encoding options
>   like CABAC and B-Slices, that are
>   powerful options but also drastically
>   increase the complexity of the file
>   and the power needed to decode the
>   video content. Maybe even more
>   crucially, G1 video has to be follow
>   very strict resolution limits, as no
>   video can be wider than 480 pixels
>   across and no higher than 368 pixels.
>   Bitrate does not appear to be nearly
>   as strict.  I’ve gotten the G1 to play
>   files with surprisingly high bitrates,
>   up to 2000 kbps, but that is generally
>   way overkill for files with sub-SD
>   resolutions.

The same guy wrote a nice MeGUI encoding profile and a guide [Video encoding for the Android: Step-by-Step](http://www.digitalwerks.org/2009/03/15/video-encoding-for-the-android-step-by-step/), it doesn't use Adobe Media Encoder, but MeGUI which is a very nicely build wrapper around a lot of great powerful command-line encoding utilities.